# Apereo CAS overlay Idp saml generate on Openshift

Tags: cas, idp

Has anyone came across this scenario?

Since we have to deploy the IDP/CAS server on microservice architecture on Openshift.

We don't have local storage, every time we generate the idp metadata when the pods deploy.

however, SP also need to handle the idp metadata x509 cert. Is there anyway to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As a general guideline, always ensure you have enough diagnostics data in your report and report the exact CAS version numbers that exhibit the seemingly-faulty behavior.

Since you don't mention this, I am going to point out a few resources to you:

[This link](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-SAML2-DynamicMetadata.html) describes strategies where SAML SP metadata can be managed without local storage.

[An updated version of the same page](https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Configuring-SAML2-DynamicMetadata.html) for the next CAS version describes strategies where SAML IDP metadata can be managed without local storage.

Comment: Thanks! I think from the link you mentioned. I have no way to use dynamic saml management. Since we are using 5.2.x .. sigh ==

Comment: Correct unless you write your own and please do keep in mind that cas 5.2.x is going to be decommissioned very soon.

Comment: No luck ..... i have tried to use 5.3.5 with the mongodb support of idp.
I followed every steps in the documentation, but it still require me to give the metadata location in file system[cas.authn.samlIdp.metadata.location]. Otherwise, it reports error.

I really don't sure what is the correct configuration for the mongodb idp meta setting